# задача по javascript

Tags: javascript

Почему этот код не работает?

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
  return "Hi " + otherName + ", my name is " + name;
}
```

Comment: "предсказуемый" - кем?

Comment: тоесть чтобы выводило то что я хочу

Comment: А что вы хотите?

Comment: А по теме — переменная `name` в функции `greet` не существует

Comment: судя по всему старая задачка: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713630/why-does-the-greet-function-not-return-the-expected-value

Comment: @andreymal, зато существует глобальная. Да ещё и с суперфичей - сохраняется при обновлении страницы)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
  return "Hi " + otherName + ", my name is " + this.name;
}
```

Пропущено ключевое слово **this**

```
var dave = new Person("Dave");
var hello = dave.greet("Alan"); // "Hi Alan, my name is Dave";
```

Comment: блин, все так просто было

Comment: как-то не сразу заметил